# Почему спустя время приложение перезапускается, если его свернуть?

Tags: android, activity, activity-life-cycle

Работаю с картой. Если свернуть приложение и развернуть его спустя некоторое время, приложение перезапускается.

Читал, что если возможность отключить такое поведение, но не могу найти как.

Comment: Отключить такое поведение нельзя, так работает система Андроид. Она может прибивать ваше приложение, когда вздумается. Наоброт, чтобы сымитировать такое поведение, во время разработки и тестирования полезно включать [Don't keep activities](https://habr.com/ru/post/221679/) в настройках разработчика.

Comment: Если вы хотите восстанавливать состояние вашей Активити, то я в своем ответе привел один из способов, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Система Андроид не гарантирует, что приложение не будет выгружено из памяти. Для того, чтобы не терять состояние, необходимо его сохранять.

Рассмотрим простой пример. На экране текст и кнопка. Нажатие на кнопку увеличивает счетчик `counter` на единицу и вставляет в текст.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;
    private int counter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            counter++;
            updateViews();
        });
    }

    private void updateViews() {
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }
}
```

Каждое нажатие на кнопку — это пользовательский ввод, к нему нужно относиться бережно и не терять то, что вводил пользователь.

Если мы свернем приложение, система Андроид может прибить процесс нашего приложения, если посчитает нужным (например, если на телефоне будет заканчиваться память). Пользовательский ввод будет утерян безвозвратно.

Чтобы устранить этот недостаток, в Активити переопределяем [`onSaveInstanceState()`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#oncreate) и сохраняем все, что нам нужно. В нашем случае это текущее состояние счетчика:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        state.putInt("com.example.counter", counter);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    }
```

Восстанавливаем значение счетчика в методе `onCreate()`:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("com.example.counter");
            updateViews();
        }
    }
```

Если вы хотите проверить, как будет вести приложение при нехватке памяти, включите на устройстве режим [Don't keep activities](https://habr.com/ru/post/221679/) («Не сохранять операции») в настройках разработчика.

В таком режиме вы сразу увидите все недостатки вашего приложения при сворачивании и разворачивании.